# substr strpos help

Tags: php, string

The script below pulls a summary of the content in $description and if a period is found in the first 50 characters, it returns the first 50 characters and the period. However, the flaw is, when no period exists in the content, it just returns the first character.

```
function get_cat_desc($description){
    $the_description = strip_tags($description);
    if(strlen($the_description) > 50 ) 
        return SUBSTR( $the_description,0,STRPOS( $the_description,".",50)+1);
        else return  $the_description;}
```

I'd like to make it so that if no period is found, it returns up until the first empty space after 50 characters (so it doesn't cut a word off) and appends "..."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best bet is to use regular expression. This will match your $description up to $maxLength (2nd argument in function) but will continue until it finds the next space.

```
function get_cat_desc($description, $max_length = 50) {
    $the_description = strip_tags($description);
    if(strlen($the_description) > $max_length && preg_match('#^\s*(.{'. $max_length .',}?)[,.\s]+.*$#s', $the_description, $matches)) {
        return $matches[1] .'...';
    } else {
        return $the_description;
    }
}
```

Comment: This one works great too. However, it sometimes results in 4 dots instead of 3, and also stops on commas in addition to periods.

Comment: I've updated my regular expression to account for these circumstances. It should work exactly as you described now.

Comment: bingo! Thanks for your help with this.

Answer (score 3):

I think it just needs to be a little more complicated:

```
function get_cat_desc($description){
    $the_description = strip_tags($description);
    if(strlen($the_description) > 50 ) {
        if (STRPOS( $the_description,".",50) !== false) {
            return SUBSTR( $the_description,0,STRPOS( $the_description,".",50)+1);
        } else {
            return SUBSTR( $the_description,0,50) . '...';
        }
    } else {
        return  $the_description;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
$pos_period = strpos($the_description, '.');
if ($pos_period !== false && $pos_period <= 50) {
    return substr($the_description, 0, 50);
} else {
    $next_space = strpos($the_description, ' ', 50);
    if ($next_space !== false) {
        return substr($the_description, 0, $next_space) . '...';
    } else {
        return substr($the_description, 0, 50) . '...';
    }
}
```

Comment: This works fine. Any way to extend it so that it doesn't cut the word off in the middle? ie, go forward to the next empty space, then append the "..."?

Answer (score 0):

use substr_count to find it and then do substr(,0,50)